# Returning QNames from user-defined function

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to transform a WSDL definition into another format for further processing, but I ran into a problem. I can't seem to return QName-values from a function, without them being turned into a string.

I reduced the file to the following, while retaining the error behavior. The original function was supposed to translate non-prefixed values using the `target-namespace` attribute from the containing `<xs:schema>` or `<wsdl:definitions>`.

**Example XSLT document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="my:resolve-QName2" as="xs:QName">
        <xsl:param name="name" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="resolve-QName($name,$element)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/definitions">
        <xsl:variable name="qname" select="my:resolve-QName2('xs:string',.)" as="xs:QName"/>
        <QName>
            <prefix><xsl:value-of select="prefix-from-QName($qname)"/></prefix>
            <local><xsl:value-of select="local-name-from-QName($qname)"/></local>
            <namespace><xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri-from-QName($qname)"/></namespace>
        </QName>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QName>
    <prefix>xs</prefix>
    <local>string</local>
    <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
</QName>
```

When running the above code, the Saxon 9.3.0.5 XSLT processor is stopping with an error:

> `Required item type of result of function my:resolve-QName2() is xs:QName. Cannot convert string to type {xs:QName}`

It seems the engine is first casting the QName into a string, and then trying to cast it back to QName, which fails. If I remove the two `as="xs:QName"`, I get the following error:

> `Required item type of first argument of prefix-from-QName() is xs:QName. Cannot convert string to type {xs:QName}`

How can I return a QName from a function?

Is this a bug in Saxon XSLT processor, or something I have misunderstood about XSLT?

Is there any XSLT engine that is able to process the above file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is here**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="resolve-QName($name,$element)"/>
```

This produces a text node (string) from the QName that `resolve-QName()` returns.

However the `my:resolve-QName2` is declared as of type `xs:QName` -- not of `xs:string` and this causes the correctly reported error.

**Solution**:

Replace the above with:

```
<xsl:sequence select="resolve-QName($name,$element)"/>
```

**Now when the corrected transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/xslt"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:function name="my:resolve-QName2" as="xs:QName">
            <xsl:param name="name" as="xs:string"/>
            <xsl:param name="element" as="element()"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="resolve-QName($name,$element)"/>
        </xsl:function>

        <xsl:template match="/definitions">
            <xsl:variable name="qname" select="my:resolve-QName2('xs:string',.)" as="xs:QName"/>
            <QName>
                <prefix><xsl:value-of select="prefix-from-QName($qname)"/></prefix>
                <local><xsl:value-of select="local-name-from-QName($qname)"/></local>
                <namespace><xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri-from-QName($qname)"/></namespace>
            </QName>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<definitions xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<QName>
   <prefix>xs</prefix>
   <local>string</local>
   <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
</QName>
```

Comment: Ok. Always use `<xsl:sequence/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of/>` with functions.  A bit counter-intuitive, but it works.

Comment: @MizardX: Not only with functions. Use `<xsl:value-of>` if you want to cause atomization / conversion to string, and/or if you want to use its `separator` attribute

Comment: When we introduced the data model changes in XSLT 2.0 we seriously considered using (xsl:value-of, xsl:text) for the instructions that are now called (xsl:sequence, xsl:value-of), but the backwards compatbility implications were too severe. So, yes, try to remember that these two instructions don't do quite what their names might suggest.